# error on calling a django rest framework endpoint from the same server

Tags: python, django, multithreading, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I have an API endpoint let's say `sampleapi.domain.com/api/v1/1` that worked well in development, both locally `(127.0.0.1)` and online `sampleapi-dev.domain.com`, but when I call the same endpoint `sampleapi.domain.com/api/v1/1` from the server from which the call is being made `sampleapi.domain.com`, I get

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
> 0)

which is unusual since the same code works in development and online. HTTP code returned was 500 instead of 200 (what was returned for the same API call in local testing and development server)

When I changed how I'm starting `gunicorn`

from `gunicorn --certfile=crt --keyfile=key --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 a.wsgi`

to `gunicorn --certfile=crt --keyfile=key --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 a.wsgi -w 1 --threads 2`

This seems to solve the error, but I'm not entirely sure why that is the case.

Was it that the single thread was not available to call the API because it was busy loading the page the API is on?
If this isn't the reason, what could be the reason?

```
File "/path/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
 response = get_response(request)
File "/path/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/path/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/path/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 40, in inner
return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/path/png/script.py", line 128, in get_api
 return response.json()
File "/path/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 910, in json
 return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
 return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
 obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
 raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

`get_api`

```
def get_api():
    url = 'https://sampleapi.domain.com/api/v1/1'
    params = {'Authorization': 'Token ' + os.environ.get("token")}
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=params)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        return "Could not grab api text."

    return response.json()
```

Comment: You usually get this exception if you try to decode the JSON without checking the response code first. Always check the HTTP response code!

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that in the question. HTTP response code returned 500

Comment: Then there should be an error traceback in the log / console.

Comment: I added a traceback. I do not get this error in development at all. This only happens when I try to use call an API hosted on the same server without specifying more than one thread when gunicorn starts. No error when I call `gunicorn` with `-w 1 --threads 2`, but not without.

Comment: This is the badly handled clients exception (see above). We need the server exception.

Comment: What is this `return response.json()` ? You should be returning a `Response` object, not a dict/json directly. Show what's in the `get_api`. Also, I really can't believe a few gunicorn flags could fix this problem. I see you're making a request to the external API. Can you show the response from it?

Comment: @TomWojcik I added a copy of `get_api`. When I call the function from `https://sampleapi-dev.domain.com` it works, but not from `https://sampleapi.domain.com`

Comment: Oh, this questions is tagged with Django and DRF so I thought those are DRF views. Anyway, added a response. You need to see a log to understand what's happening. There's no way around it. If you know it's 500, the can't you see the log in your Django app to understand what caused it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like whatever

`response = requests.get(url, headers=params)`

sometimes returns, is not a `json`.

If you have a hard time debugging and this problem occurs only in certain environments where you can't depend on the debugger and you depend on the 3rd party response, just add a log there.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def get_api():
    url = 'https://sampleapi.domain.com/api/v1/1'
    params = {'Authorization': 'Token ' + os.environ.get("token")}
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=params)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        return "Could not grab api text."
    
    # .debug or .info or whatever level of logging you use
    logger.debug(f"Status code is {response.status_code} and text is {response.text}")

    return response.json()
```

If, as you mentioned, it's 500 and it returns a generic Server error, you won't be able to debug the issue from the client as it doesn't point to any potential solution.

If you can see Django app logs, just see what it returns. If you can't see any error, add `sentry`. If you can't do that, ask someone who is in control of the server.

It's probably `ALLOWED_HOSTS` or cors.

Answer (score -1):

Try use it

```
gunicorn Config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 3
```